# Music video about family awaiting end of the world by meteors

Tags: story-identification, music-identification

I'd like to identify a music video with a definite sci-fi theme. I saw it during a random surf of YouTube 2-4 years ago.

I've no idea who the actress was but I believe it was a female singer as the MC in the video was a young woman. I have no memory of the music or lyrics, nor do I know if the artist was a big name or not as I don't follow the charts.

It depicted a short wordless story about the end of the world. The woman and, I think, her boyfriend's family are celebrating a last meal together in a cabin in woodland. It looks like Norway/Alaska/Canada.

During the meal a little girl is overcome with fear and hides in her room where the MC runs to comfort her.

Later they all build a fire outside and stand around stoically waiting for the end, staring up at the night sky while meteors come raining down, an image which has haunted me.

---

<sub>**Note**. It's not [*One Last Time*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPgEgaPk62M) (Ariana Grande) or [*You Are The One*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rv_FnbBqnWs) (Safia)</sub>

Comment: Do you realize that YouTube stores your complete watch history forever? Assuming you were logged in.

Comment: I never log in - don't like them storing my info - never had a use for it before.